# Spring boot ow to build a war file without mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, deployment

I have a Spring boot project that needs to build a war file and deploy to a separate container. I have built the war file out but the deployment needs to connect the MySQL database first like most Spring Boot projects. Is it possible to deploy the war without connecting to the Mysql database?

Comment: How are you connecting to database? Using Hiberate, JPA or JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable autoconfiguration.

Here is an example of disabling using properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
```

You can also use annotations but I do not prefer this way, as I externalize the properties.

Annotations like:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
```